# LDAP authentication with Spring Boot 1.4.1

Tags: spring-boot, ldap

I am using Spring boot and developing REST services and want to integrate with LDAP authentication security mechanism.

I googled a lot but did not get a concrete solution as such. I am looking for a complete example.

Also I am using POSTMAN client and want to know how to use it to test the LDAP authentication.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: You should look at Spring LDAP: https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for ur response..Actually I did it but here its using ldif file instead of actual LDAP, so stuck at that point..

Comment: @Daniel Olszewski
Can you pls provide me a working example Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html)

This was actually surprisingly simple. Thank you, Boot.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/yourstuff/**").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/your/protectedstuff/**").authenticated()
               .and()
               .httpBasic()
               .permitAll();
   }

   @Configuration
   protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

       @Override
       public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
               auth.authenticationProvider(new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("DOMAINNAME","LDAP SERVER URI"));


       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi arseniyandru, thanks for ur response..i have added the above class but after restarting the server its not detecting this security class. I mean,  i dont see anything in my logs..

Comment: sending u more information for clarity..
Simple controller
RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 ResponseBody
 public String testPing(RequestParam("param") String param) {
  return param;
 }
RequestMapping(value = { "/test" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ResponseBody String retrieve() {
     return "hello";
}
I want to authenticate user against LDAP for accessing "ping" service.
usually we use like
 Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();

Comment: String ldapUrl = "<URL>";
        String principal = "uid=" + username + ",OU=" + ou + ",O=cco.org.com";
                environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        environment.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
how I use Spring boot to authenticate user to access my "ping" service.

Comment: can u pls help me on this??

Comment: Can you pls provide me a working example arseniyandru??